# How to mount my iPod Touch 4G?

Tags: 9.10, ipod

When I plug in my 32GB iPod Touch 4G, it mounts a 1GB drive. Rhythmbox does not react, neither does Banshee.

Any ideas how to copy my music?

The output of `df` with ipod plugged is:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             28834716   4347480  23022512  16% /
udev                   1026788       288   1026500   1% /dev
none                   1026788      1496   1025292   1% /dev/shm
none                   1026788       204   1026584   1% /var/run
none                   1026788         0   1026788   0% /var/lock
none                   1026788         0   1026788   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda6             96124904  62709456  28532496  69% /home
```

and for `sudo fdisk -l` also with ipod plugged:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009b4b0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        3647    29294496   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            3648       15927    98639100    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            3648        3769      979933+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6            3770       15927    97659103+  83  Linux
```

Comment: What gen ipod do you have? Which Ubuntu? With the ipod plugged in, what is the output of `df`? of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Has it previoulsy worked or is this the first time you've tried to connect it? You can install gtkpod from the software centre which will enable you to load content to the ipod independant of Rhythmbox or Banshee

Comment: @djeikyb I updated, but what fdisk -1 will do?

Comment: @Mark Rooney No, it never worked. I activate it on the Apple store. I'll try gtkpod and I post here the result..

Comment: @Mark Rooney gtkpod also doesn't recognize it..

Comment: See `man fdisk`. It gives a listing of your disks, including size and device path. `df` shows what's mounted, `fdisk -l` shows everything linux knows about.

Comment: @djeikyb there it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there are issues with the iOS firmware on the iPod Touch 4G and Ubuntu - there is a long and detailed  post on Ubuntu Forums [here](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1576249) detailing methods to troubleshoot and fix.

Comment: The solution uses jailbreak, is there a solution without jailbreak?

Comment: Looks like there's no way, so I'll install Windows in dual boot..

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 alpha does the trick :D

Comment: Oh, no, it doesn't. It recognize the ipod, but the musics will not appear in the ipod player after sync with Banshee (gtkpod doesn't recognize it well). There are issues with the 4G. I'll use dual boot.

Comment: @Tom: For me on iPod touch 2G on 11.04, works like a charm. (Not jailbroken). I'm on iOS 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal. Enter these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and reboot. Your iOS device should work now. Mine did.

Comment: Nothing changed. The device is still mounted as 1GB, and it's not recognized by Rhytmbox, Banshee or gtkpod.

Comment: What iOS version are you using? 4.2.1 or 4.1?

Comment: Ahh. You're using 9.10. Open up a terminal and type in "sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice0" (without the quotes) and now it should work. Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 9.10 you'll need to install a package or two from the Package Manager to enable iPod support. Open it up via *System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager* and type in the following for your search parameters.

```
libimobiledevice
```

Check them and install, restart your machine! After that you should be able to sync and load your iPod without any issues :)