# 4th gen. iPod Touch and Syncing with Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 12.1

Tags: rhythmbox, ipod

I recently set-up a dual boot with Ubuntu 12.1 and Windows 8 on my Asus Vivobook. I have a 4th gen. iPod Touch that I'd like to sync with Rhythmbox but unfortunately it will not sync my music.

When I plug the iPod into my machine I get several windows telling me that documents cannot be read and I also  get a window which says, "iPod detected," but nothing happens. The window stays blank, and by this time Rhythmbox usually freezes up.

I have searched for some time now over the past two days and have yet to find out whether or not iPods running iOS6 can be syned with Rhythmbox. There are people that seem to have success via some methods while other people get nothing via the same tools.

So, my question is: Is there any way to sync the music on my 4th gen. iPod Touch with Rhythmbox while running Ubuntu 12.1?

Comment: I report the same problem. +1

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/25908/how-to-mount-my-ipod-touch-4g, which has a good answer.