# how to mount ipod touch 4th generation 16gb

Tags: 13.04, ipod

i am used to the easy way on windows. just open the itunes and voila your work is done. here it is a bit different i see. i tried using rhythmbox and also downloaded gpod. but seems like Rhythmbox only supports upto 3rd generation ipods. My being the 4th gen. i am unable to load files or even mount it easily.For this i have downloaded gtkpod ipod manager. but cant really understand nothing. can you please help, and tell me how to go about it :(

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/25908/how-to-mount-my-ipod-touch-4g, which has a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : (http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/07/07/how-to-use-gtkpod-to-manage-your-ipod-in-ubuntu/)

Works for me :)

This is a bit outdated - Skip the installation instruction and go to step 2 of "Using gtkpod".

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't seem to be an open-source way to put audio onto a 4th gen iPod touch.

I tried gtkpod and banshee, but both are based on [libgpod](http://gtkpod.org/wiki/Libgpod).  That wiki page indicates that the current (0.8.0) release only has read-only support for iPod touch 4th gen.

I ran into the same problem as you, with a 4th gen ipod touch. (except maybe you weren't even getting read-only support). The GUIs do a terrible job at alerting you to the fact that your changes can't be saved. :/