# How do I mount this ipod? fdisk won't even tell me where it is

Tags: usb, mount, ipod

Trying to mount a 4th gen ipod on Ubuntu 15.10. It shows up in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05ac:1203 Apple, Inc. iPod 4.Gen Grayscale 40G
```

But I don't see anything in `fdisk -l`:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2050047   2048000 1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    2050048   2582527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sda3    2582528   2844671    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2844672 256555609 253710938  121G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  457578496 485437439  27858944 13.3G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  485437440 500117503  14680064    7G Intel Fast Flash
/dev/sda7  256557056 441047039 184489984   88G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  441047040 457578495  16531456  7.9G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Not for nothing, `fdisk` seems to hang there, without ever showing me the contents of `/dev/sdb`.

There's a similar question from 2011: [How to mount my iPod Touch 4G?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25908/how-to-mount-my-ipod-touch-4g) but it seems specific to 9.10.

I have `gtkpod` installed, but it also doesn't seem to see the device (no big surprise since it isn't mounted). The answer to this question [how to mount ipod touch 4th generation 16gb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331134/how-to-mount-ipod-touch-4th-generation-16gb) points off to a website that walks through using `gtkpod` but also doesn't say what to do if `gtkpod` can't even see the device.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 20` and `sudo lsblk -f` about 10–30 seconds after plugging the iPod in? Does the iPod operating system think it is plugged in, when you plug it in?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the ipod is just a content partition without partition table. In that case you'd mount with "mount /dev/sdb /mnt". There should be some traces in /var/log/syslog as to what the device could be called; i.e. whether it is /dev/sdb or not.

Comment: -1 From personal experience I can tell you, it is not.